# Intuition for the construction of the product topology and its equivalence to the euclidian metric

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, intuition

While I have been provided a proof for the previous statement, I still cannot fully grasp why the euclidian metric [ $d(x,y)=((x_1-y_1)^2+...(x_{n}-y_{n})^2)^{1/2}$] generates the same topology as the product topology.

I'm requesting a description for the basis elements for the product topology, as well as an alternative definition from those provided in wikipedia and Munkres' topoology. I do not understand how it is constructed, and why it generates the same topology as the euclidian metric.

Comment: Well, for a finite product, box topology and product topology are equal. Consider an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, you can fill the ball with open cubes and vice versa.

Comment: For an infinite product, box topology and product topology differ. Product topology is the least topology that makes all projection maps $\pi_i :\prod X_i \rightarrow X_i$ continuous, while box topology is strictly coarser than the product topology. Box topology contains much more information than the product topology, hence many beautiful theorems don't work in Box topology while they hold in product topology.

Comment: There is no reason to consider Box topology natural, since Product topology is the one that makes all projections maps continuous and evey meaningful (synthetic)topology on $\prod X_i$ must have this property so that one can stay in the category of topological spaces. Moreover, there are many topologies between product&box topologies. For example, (product topology) $\subset$ (topology of compact convergence) $\subset$ (topology of uniform convergence) $\subset$ (box topology)$, and these are all useful depending on one's purpose

Comment: isn't the product topology coarser than the box topology?

Comment: @Rubertos also: why do they differ in the infinite case, why is the product topology, the "least topology" [I take this to mean coarsest] such that the projections are continuous/why is that such an important fact? Do you have some intuitive description of the product topology, that isn't defined by its properties? I don't mean to sound demanding, I'm just missing something conceptually about this particular topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont't think of finest or coarsest topologies with certain properties. Instead just look at the problem in an intuitive geometric way.

Given that the topology on ${\mathbb R}$ is "generated" by open intervals $\ ]a,b[\ $ the *product topology* on ${\mathbb R}^n$ is generated by open boxes, i.e. cartesian products $\prod_{i=1}^n\>]a_i,b_i[\>$ of open intervals. A set is *open*, if it is the union of such boxes. Since any finite intersection of such boxes is (empty or)  again such a box it follows that we have indeed a topology on ${\mathbb R}^n$.

In order to prove that this topology coincides with the topology coming from the euclidean metric it is sufficient to show that any euclidean neighborhood of any point $p$ (it is sufficient to consider $p=0$) is also a box neighborhood of $p$, and vice versa.

I'll do one half of the proof for you: Given an euclidean neighborhood $U$ of $0$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $0\in U_\epsilon(0)\subset U$. The open box
$$B:=\left\{x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)\>\biggm|\>|x_k|<{\epsilon\over\sqrt{n}} \ (1\leq k\leq n)\right\}$$
is a neighborhood of $0$ with respect to the product topology. For each $x\in B$ one has $|x|^2<n{\displaystyle{\epsilon^2\over n}}$, or $|x|<\epsilon$. This shows that in fact
$$0\in B\subset U_\epsilon(0)\subset U\ ;$$
in other words: $U$ is also a neighborhood of $0$ with respect to the box topology. Since $U$ was arbitrary we are done.

Comment: Isn't the box topology also generated by open boxes of open intervals? What is the difference then?

Comment: I know that the product topokogy is coarser, i dont understand why. Im assuming there is a critical difference in the construction that i am not understanding

Comment: In the finite dimensional case there is no difference. In the infinite dimensional case the box topology is *finer* than the product topology. (There is an error in @Rubertos second comment to your question.) The difference is the following: With respect to the product topology a neighborhood of $p$ is only restricted with respect to a finite number of coordinates, while a box neighborhood may be restricted with respect to all coordinates.

Comment: I understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This particular problem is due I think to an excessive focus on topology at the expense of geometry, which sheds more light on the matter.  The point here is that any two norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent.  It follows in particular that the box topology is the same as the topology defined by the Euclidean metric.